# ANTLR4 setText function not working with parser rules

Tags: java, antlr, identifier, settext

Why can not I use setText function in parser rules ?

For example:

```
normalClassDeclaration
:   classModifier* 'class' Identifier typeParameters? superclass? superinterfaces? classBody
    {
    $Identifier.setText("TEST");
    }
;
```

If I generate the parser and lexer with this grammar, the parser doesn't know the function setText.
If I do this in the lexer rules, there is no problem and he is changing every identifier to "TEST"

```
Identifier
:   JavaLetter JavaLetterOrDigit*
{
setText("V");
}
;
```

But he should only change the identifier when its  a class/function/variable identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Identifier` is of type [org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Token.html). It is a interface providing only getter (f.e. *getText()*).

following will work:

```
normalClassDeclaration
:   classModifier* 'class' Identifier typeParameters? superclass? superinterfaces? classBody
    {
    ((CommonToken)$Identifier).setText("TEST");
    }
;
```

Comment: Thank you. Was very helpful.